# Trigger change in input slider using MouseEvent based on position

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, eventtrigger

With the given code:

```
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.type='range';
i.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
i.style.height=window.innerHeight + 'px';
i.style.position = "absolute";
i.style.top = 0;
i.style.left = 0;
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

I get a slider covering something like the whole viewport, and anywhere i click will move the slider point to the equivalent x position. When I try to simulate a mouse click on a range input element to move the slider point using a MouseEvent i do not get the same result

```
var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    button: 0,
    detail: 1,
    screenX: 20,
    screenY: 50,
    clientX: 20,
    clientY: 50,
    bubbles: true,
    composed: true
});
i.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

How can I trigger the slider bar to move to the corresponding x position in the same way programmatically as with the mouse?

Answer (score 2):

Range inputs determine their position based on their value, max, and min. You don't need to go so far as simulating a mouse click; just set its value accordingly. You're not setting the min and max yourself when creating the input, so it will use the default range of [0, 100]. Which actually makes the math quite easy.

In general, you'd get the slider at the right position with this formula:

```
i.value = (desired_x - min_x) / width * (max - min) + min
```

Since max = 100, min = 0, min_x = 0, and width = window.innerWidth, that simplifies to this:

```
i.value = desired_x / window.innerWidth * 100
```

Comment: You are right in that this would be simpler, but I was hoping to trigger the change of input value based on the position of another dom element through user interaction, without clicking on the slider itself or using keyboard keys. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I gave you the solution to changing the value without clicking the slider or using the keyboard. What other DOM element should trigger it, and through what user interaction?

Comment: I want to be able to trigger it programmatically, but based on some screen coordinates. If it is as you describe, and the value corresponds to a fraction of the width of the element (as opposed to there being some builtin padding on both sides), then I would, in general, have to find the element position and shape via `getBoundingClientRect()` and compute its value based on the formula you show with `event_x` as `desired_x` and `rect.x` as `min_x`, `rect.width` as `width`. `max` and `min` could be extracted from the element attributes with default values as described. I guess thats what wanted